# Mobile design and images sizes problem

Tags: mobile, android, mobile-application, screen-resolution

We are developing a mobile App for a website, we have a problem in scaling images for 2x and 3x mobile screens.

The website allows users to upload images, and all images that were uploaded in the past have max width of **480px**, on the mobile we want to show these images at max width of **320 points** which means:

- On 1x screen the image width will be 320px
- On 2x screen the image width will be 640px
- On 3x screen the image width will be 960px

But the max available size we have is **480px** and we can't upscale the images,

What we can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for  you there's nothing you can do if `all images that were uploaded in the past have max width of 480px`.

There's no way to upscale an image without loosing image quality.

If the users uploading images do so via a personal account  you could show a message next to the image asking the user to upload a higher quality version of the same image.